# Adding a complex object to JObject using a delimited path/key

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am working with Jsons which *I don't know their structure in advanced*. Just for example:

```
{
    "OrganizationData": {
        "Org1": {
            "Name": "Rega And Dodli",
            "EmployessNum": "100000000"
         },
         "Org2": {
            "Name": "Sami And Soso",
            "EmployessNum": "2"
         }
    }
}
```

I'm currently getting values by using the `SelectToken` method to which I can pass a key with a sub key like this:

```
var token = myJObject.SelectToken("OrganizationData.Org1")
```

This works fine. Now I want to add a new entry to the JSON using a string like that, something like:

```
myJObject.Add("OrganizationData.Org3", myValueJson);
```

but calling add like that directly just adds a new key to the json called "OrganizationData.Org3" and not creating a new sub key called "Org3" inside "OrganizationData" like the current "Org1" and "Org2".

How can I add a new value with a delimited string like needed?

Comment: JSON doesn't have subkeys. `OrganizationData.Org1` is a JSON Path expression, not a subkey

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OK. So what is the answer?

Comment: What is `myValueJson`?

Comment: @haim770 It's a json string that will be added as the value of that given key or more correctly be converted to a jobject which will be added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON doesn't have subkeys or delimited keys. `OrganizationData.Org1` is a LINQ to JSON search expression, not a subkey.

To add `Org3` you can use one of the many ways available to modify a JSON object. You can add a child element to `OrganizationData` or a sibling to one of the other `Org` nodes.

To add a child element to a node, you could use `.SelectToken("OrganizationData")` if you don't already have a reference to it, and use `JObject.Add` to add the new node. You'll have to cast the result to `JObject` first, as `SelectToken` returns a `JToken`. If there's a chance that `OrganizationData` is an array, you'll have to check the type too.

For example:

```
var token = myJObject.SelectToken("OrganizationData");
if(token is JObject orgObj)
{
    orgObj.Add("Org3",myValueJson);
}
```

**Working with unknown paths**

The same thing works if the path is specified at runtime. In this case, all that's needed is to separate the last part from the rest of the path, perhaps using [String.LastIndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_Char_):

```
var lastDot=path.LastIndexOf('.');
if (lastDot<0)
{
    //Oops! There's no dot. What do we do now?
}
var parent=path.Substring(0,lastDot);
var key=path.Substring(lastDot+1);

var token = myJObject.SelectToken(parent);
if(token is JObject orgObj)
{
    orgObj.Add(key,myValueJson);
}
```

You'll have to decide what to do if the path contains no dot. Is this an invalid path? Or should a new object be added under the root object?

Comment: I don't know the structure of the json in advanced. All I have is a full string of some json I know nothing about and a key like "key1.key2.key3" and I need to add a new jobject to that path

Comment: You know enough already - that `OrganizationData` is an object, containing properties, not an array or a value. Knowing the path means you *can* check if that object exists and if not, find the parent specified in the path, and insert the new object. All you need to do is split the path

Comment: I don't know that there is something called "OrganizationData". It was just an example of a json to show what I want to do

Comment: You know there is a parent path in there and a new item name. I posted how to extract them with `String.LastIndexOf`

Comment: OK that can work. but isn't there something built in that I can use without the need to parse the path?

Comment: Why are you asking? The code is trivial and one could argue that what you ask is specific to your application. *Patching* an existing document on the other hand is far more common and a lot trickier, so it's supported eg by [PopulateObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject.htm). An example is shown in [Modify existing object with new partial JSON data using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511675/modify-existing-object-with-new-partial-json-data-using-json-net)